# Discord Bot запись голоса

Tags: golang, discord-api, discord

Нужно реализовать Echo-бота для дискорда.
Функционал будет немного другой, но проблема в записи голоса из дискорда.
Голос не записывается. Нашёл example, но он тоже не работает.
https://github.com/bwmarrin/dgvoice/blob/master/examples/echo/main.go
Что может быть не так? Может есть какие-то ограничения дискорда на получение голосовых пакетов?